# With CKEditor 4.3.2 and ASP.NET - Moving Mouse to right causes event error in IE9 on server but not locally

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

So I am using CKEditor 4.3.2 in my ASP.NET application. When I run the application locally it runs fine in IE9. When I publish it to the server and hit it with IE9 and  click in the ckeditor text area in IE9 and then move my mouse over (the right edge of the text area only) I get the popup error below :

*SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'
ckeditor.js, line 78 character 434*

Any ideas on how to resolve this? - Thanks

This is the block of code the error originates when I go into debug mode, I have **bolded** the line that it is complaining about below in the ckeditor.js.

dClass:function(a){var b=this.$.className;b&&(RegExp("(?:^|\s)"+a+"(?:\s|$)",
"").test(b)||(b=b+(" "+a)));this.$.className=b||a},removeClass:function(a){var b=this.getAttribute("class");if(b){a=RegExp("(?:^|\s+)"+a+"(?=\s|$)","i");if(a.test(b))(b=b.replace(a,"").replace(/^\s+/,""))?this.setAttribute("class",b):this.removeAttribute("class")}return this},hasClass:function(a){return RegExp("(?:^|\s+)"+a+"(?=\s|$)","").test(this.getAttribute("class"))},append:function(a,b){typeof a=="string"&&(a=this.getDocument().createElement(a));b?this.$.insertBefore(a.$,this.$.firstChild):
this.$.appendChild(a.$);return a},appendHtml:function(a){if(this.$.childNodes.length){var b=new CKEDITOR.dom.element("div",this.getDocument());b.setHtml(a);b.moveChildren(this)}else this.setHtml(a)},appendText:function(a){this.$.text!=void 0?this.$.text=this.$.text+a:this.append(new CKEDITOR.dom.text(a))},appendBogus:function(a){if(a||CKEDITOR.env.needsBrFiller||CKEDITOR.env.opera){for(a=this.getLast();a&&a.type==CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT&&!CKEDITOR.tools.rtrim(a.getText());)a=a.getPrevious();if(!a||!a.is||
!a.is("br")){a=CKEDITOR.env.opera?this.getDocument().createText(""):this.getDocument().createElement("br");CKEDITOR.env.gecko&&a.setAttribute("type","_moz");this.append(a)}}},breakParent:function(a){var b=new CKEDITOR.dom.range(this.getDocument());b.setStartAfter(this);b.setEndAfter(a);a=b.extractContents();b.insertNode(this.remove());a.insertAfterNode(this)},contains:CKEDITOR.env.ie||CKEDITOR.env.webkit?function(a){var b=this.$;**return a.type!=CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT?b.contains(a.getParent().$):b!=**
a.$&&b.contains(a.$)}:function(a){return!!(this.$.compareDocumentPosition(a.$)&16)},focus:function(){function a(){try{this.$.focus()}catch(b){}}return function(b){b?CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout(a,100,this):a.call(this)}}(),getHtml:function(){var a=this.$.innerHTML;return CKEDITOR.env.ie?a.replace(/<\?[^>]*>/g,""):a},getOuterHtml:function(){if(this.$.outerHTML)return this.$.outerHTML.replace(/<\?[^>]*>/,"");var a=this.$.ownerDocument.createElement("div");a.appendChild(this.$.cloneNode(true));return a.innerHTML},

...

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions here.

**Redownload CKEditor from the download page, replace the old
installation (remember to backup your configuration file), clear
browser's cache and the problem should be gone now.**

Some versions of CKEditor have issues with SSL. This will fix that.

-
or -

**Clear your browsers cache `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `DEL` in IE when your on the server site.**

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to the application and noticed the error is not popping up now. It seems temperamental. The site is not SSL, but it may be the caching issue, and I will try that when I see it again.

Comment: You do know I am talking about CKEditor, not CKFinder right?